# Shell: Extract some code from HTML

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep

I have the following code snippet from a HTML file:

```
<div id="rwImages_hidden" style="display:none;">
    <img src="http://example.com/images/I/520z3AjKzHL._SL500_AA300_.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
    <img src="http://example.com/images/I/519z3AjKzHL._SL75_AA30_.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
    <img src="http://example.com/images/I/31F-sI61AyL._SL75_AA30_.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
    <img src="http://example.com/images/I/71k-DIrs-8L._AA30_.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
    <img src="http://example.com/images/I/61CCOS0NGyL._AA30_.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
</div>
```

I want to extract the code

```
520z3AjKzHL
519z3AjKzHL
31F-sI61AyL
71k-DIrs-8L
61CCOS0NGyL
```

from the HTML.

Please note that: `<img src="" style="display:none;"/>` must be used because there are other similar urls in HTML file but I only what the ones between `<img src="" style="display:none;"/>`.

My Code is:

```
cat HTML | grep -Po '(?<img src="http://example.com/images/I/).*?(?=.jpg" style="display:none;"/>)'
```

Something seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by using [positive look ahead / look behind:](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
cat HTML | grep -Po "(?<=<img src=\"http://example.com/images/I/).*?(?=\._.*.jpg\" style=\"display:none;\"/>)"
```

---

Demonstration:

- [ideone.com link](http://ideone.com/dQLZD)

---

Regexp breakdown:

- `.*?` match all characters reluctantly
- `(?<=<img src=...ges/I/)` preceeded by `<img .../I/`
- `(?=\._...ne;\"/>)` succeeded by `._...ne;\"/>`

Comment: UUOC.. hahahah funny page. the cat was from the OP

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were looking for a lookbehind to start, which is what was throwing the error.

`(?<=foo)` not `(?<foo)`.

This gives the result case you specified, but I do not know if you need up until the JPG or not:

```
cat HTML | grep -Po '(?<=img src="http://example.com/images/I/)[^.]*'
```

Up until and excluding the JPG would be:

```
cat HTML | grep -Po '(?<=img src="http://example.com/images/I/).*(?=.jpg)'
```

Comment: You're not using the `display:none` information, which the OP states is required. See my answer for the full expression.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that part. Your regex is more precise, and in this case necessary.

Answer (score 0):

And if you consider gawk as being a valid bash solution:

```
awk -F'[/|\._]' -v img='/<img src="" style="display:none;"\/>/' '/img/{print $7}' file
```